Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{100}x^k\right)-100}{x-1}$ two ways gives different results
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{100}x^k\right)-100}{x-1}$$
So I tried to do this problem with 2 methods. Method 1 gives me the correct answer whereas method 2 doesn't. Can someone help me point out my mistake in method 2. In method 2 I directly used the standard result in "part" of the problem. I'm not sure if we can't do that? Because in few other questions it gives me the correct answer.

Method 1:
\begin{equation}
\Big(\sum^{100}_{k=1}x^k\Big)-100 = \sum^{100}_{k=1}(x^k-1)
\end{equation}
Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{x^k-a^k}{x-a}=ka^{k-1}$ for all $k\neq-1$ and $a$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\Big(\sum^{100}_{k=1}x^k\Big)-100 =\sum^{100}_{k=1}\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{x^k-1}{x-1}= \sum^{100}_{k=1} k=\frac{100}{101}{2}=5050
\end{equation}

Method 2
\begin{equation}
\frac{\Big(\sum^{100}_{k=1}x^k\Big)-100}{x-1} = \frac{\tfrac{x(x^{100}-1)}{x-1}-100}{x-1}
\end{equation}
Again, using the standard limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{x^k-a^k}{x-a}=ka^{k-1}$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{\tfrac{x(x^{100}-1)}{x-1}-100}{x-1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{100 x-100}{x-1}=100
\end{equation}
since $\frac{x^{100}-1}{x-1}\rightarrow100$ as $x\rightarrow1$.



Please don't use pictures of text or formulas. See
here,
why. Use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

It should be noted that both approaches are correct and the exact answer is indeed 5050 as I saw in your first method. However, your second calculation should actually look like the following:
$$\lim_{x\to 1}{\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n{x^k}-n}{x-1}}=\lim_{x\to 1}{\frac{\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}-n-1}{x-1}}=\lim_{x\to 1}{\frac{(x^{n+1}-1)-(n+1)(x-1)}{(x-1)^2}},$$
and so, by L'Hopital's rule
$$\lim_{x\to 1}{\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n{x^k}-n}{x-1}}=\lim_{x\to 1}{\frac{(n+1)x^n-(n+1)}{2(x-1)}}=\frac{n+1}{2}\lim_{x\to 1}{\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$
Regarding the (quite serious, if I may add) error you made in method 2, I think it is evident what went wrong.
Now, I'd like to also comment that method 1 is q much more pleasing approach, given how quickly you get to the final answer via this pathway.

The problem with the computation in your second approach is that you evaluated a limit within a limit, on the same variable.  You are not allowed to let $x \to 1$ of a portion of the function, then evaluate the rest of the limit, so this operation is incorrect:
$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x (\frac{x^n - 1}{x-1}) - n}{x - 1} \ne \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x nx^{n-1} - n}{x-1}.$$  In writing this, you have allowed $x \to 1$ of the interior expression $\frac{x^n - 1}{x-1}$ but the other factors and terms that depend on $x$ remain variable.  Then you have actually committed a second error, distinct from the first, which is evaluating $nx^{n-1}$ at $x = 1$ without doing so for the rest of the expression:  $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{xnx^{n-1} - n}{x-1} \ne \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{n(x-1)}{x-1} = n.$$
In particular, the first error changes the value of the limit from the correct $n(n+1)/2$ to the incorrect $n^2$, but the second error changes the incorrect value $n^2$ to $n$.  You combined both errors into a single step, but they are actually two separate steps.
That said, there are cases where separate evaluation is allowed, but only in specific circumstances; e.g.,
$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) + g(x) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x) + \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$$
if the individual limits of $f$ and $g$ on the RHS exist, and similarly,
$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) g(x) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x) \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$$ but again, only if those individual limits exist.  So for instance,
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt{1-x^2} \frac{\sin x}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt{1-x^2} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1 \cdot 1 = 1$$
is allowed, but
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt{1-x^2} \frac{\sin x}{x} \ne \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x} \lim_{x \to 0} \sin x = \infty \cdot 0 = \text{indeterminate}.$$
